# Have the first article from a model at the top displayed

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am creating a Django blog app and I was wondering if it was possible to have the first blog post as pictured in this design.

[image: wireframe]

What I have done so far is that I have been able to get the bottom three articles but I have been confused on how to approach the top post.

This is my template code so far:

```html
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
                    {% for article in articles %}
                    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-4 ">
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h2 class="card-title">{{ article.title }}</h2>
                                <p class="card-text text-muted h6"> <img class="image-size radius-of_image" src="article/{{ article.upload_image }}"> | {{ article.author }} | {{ article.created_on | date}} </p>
                                <p class="card-text">{{article.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
                                <a href="{% url 'Article' article.slug %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" and not forloop.last %}
                        <div class="row">
                            {% endif %}

                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is how my views look like

```py
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')

        articles = {
            "articles": queryset
        }

    return render(request, 'home.htm', articles)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django has several template filters which are easy to use and avoid headache of developers. You can use  {{ value|first }} to  display the first model instance in your template from  your query set